# Remove carriage return from XML file C#

Tags: c#, .net, streamreader, streamwriter, carriage-return

I need to remove carriage return from an XML file, but what i get is only an XML file with one box(\r). I wrote this:

```
    string sourceFileName = textBox1.Text;

                     StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(sourceFileName);

                     String line;
                     String newLine = null;
                     // Read and display lines from the file until the end of 
                     // the file is reached.
                     while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                     {

                         //Regex regex = new Regex(@"(\r\n|\r|\n)+");

                         newLine = line.Replace("\r\n", String.Empty);
//also tried line.Replace("\n", String.Empty).Replace("\r",String.Empty); , but no use

                         StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\manish\Desktop\output.xml");
                         sw.WriteLine(newLine);
                         sw.Close();
    }
```

What could be the problem here.

**EDIT:**

Here is the sample:

```
3C 3F 78 6D 6C 20 76 65  72 73 69 6F 6E 3D 27 31
30 27 3F 3E 3C 72 6F 6F  74 3E 20 E0 A8 8D E2 80
80 E3 B0 80 E4 8C 80 E4  A4 80 E4 90 80 E3 B8 80
E7 8C 80 E7 8C 80 E5 BC  80 E6 98 80 E6 B0 80 E3
88 80 E7 94 80 E3 8C 80  E5 BC 80 E6 B8 80 E6 88
80 E5 BC 80 E7 94 80 E3  8C 80 E5 BC 80 E6 8C 80
E3 84 80 E3 80 80 E5 BC  80 E7 8C 80 E3 84 80 E3
B0 80 E2 BC 80 E4 8C 80  E4 A4 80 E4 90 80 E3 B8
80 E2 80 80 E0 B4 80 E0  B4 80 0A 20 3C 62 6F 6F
6B 74 69 74 6C 65 3E 3C  21 5B 43 44 41 54 41 5B
5D 5D 3E 3C 2F 62 6F 6F  6B 74 69 74 6C 65 3E 3C
70 61 6E 65 6C 73 3E E0  A8 8D E3 B0 80 E7 80 80

<?xml version='10'?><root> à¨â€€ã°€äŒ€ä¤€ä€ã¸€çŒ€çŒ€å¼€æ˜€æ°€ãˆ€ç”€ãŒ€å¼€æ¸€æˆ€å¼€ç”€ãŒ€å¼€æŒ€ã„€ã€€å¼€çŒ€ã„€ã°€â¼€äŒ€ä¤€ä€ã¸€â€€à´€à´€
 <booktitle><![CDATA[]]></booktitle><panels>à¨ã°€ç€€æ„€æ¸€æ”€æ°€â€€ç€æ¤€ç€æ°€æ”€ã´€âœ€äœ€ä”€ä¼€äœ€åˆ€ä„€å€€ä €å¤€â€€åŒ€ä¬€ä¤€ä°€ä°€äˆ€å”€ä¤€ä°€ä€ä”€åˆ€âœ€ã¸€à´€à´€
<questionsAndAnswers>à¨ã°€æ €æ”€æ„€æ€æ¤€æ¸€æœ€ã¸€ã°€â„€å¬€äŒ€ä€ä„€å€ä„€å¬€ã°€æˆ€ã¸€ä¤€æ¸€ç€æ”€çˆ€ç€€çˆ€æ”€ç€æ¤€æ¸€æœ€â€€ä´€æ„€ç€€çŒ€ã°€â¼€æˆ€ã¸€å´€å´€ã¸€ã°€â¼€æ €æ”€æ„€æ€æ¤€æ¸€æœ€ã¸€à´€à´€
<question><![CDATA[<b>1 Location</b> Why is Arabia's location a good one for trade?]]></question>à¨ã°€æ„€æ¸€çŒ€çœ€æ”€çˆ€â¼€ã¸€à´€à´€
<ansCharCount>350</ansCharCount>à¨ã°€â¼€ç„€ç”€æ”€çŒ€ç€æ¤€æ¼€æ¸€çŒ€ä„€æ¸€æ€ä„€æ¸€çŒ€çœ€æ”€çˆ€çŒ€ã¸€à´€à´€
<questionsAndAnswers>à¨ã°€æ €æ”€æ„€æ€æ¤€æ¸€æœ€ã¸€ã°€â„€å¬€äŒ€ä€ä„€å€ä„€å¬€ã°€æˆ€ã¸€ä¤€æ¸€ç€æ”€çˆ€ç€€çˆ€æ”€ç€æ¤€æ¸€æœ€â€€ä´€æ„€ç€€çŒ€ã°€â¼€æˆ€ã¸€å´€å´€ã¸€ã°€â¼€æ €æ”€æ„€æ€æ¤€æ¸€æœ€ã¸€à´€à´€
<question><![CDATA[<b>2 Movement</b> Why was the location of Mecca ideal for the spread of ideas?]]></question>à¨ã°€æ„€æ¸€çŒ€çœ€æ”€çˆ€â¼€ã¸€à´€à´€
<ansCharCount>350</ansCharCount>à¨ã°€â¼€ç„€ç”€æ”€çŒ€ç€æ¤€æ¼€æ¸€çŒ€ä„€æ¸€æ€ä„€æ¸€çŒ€çœ€æ”€çˆ€çŒ€ã¸€à´€à´€
</panel>à¨ã°€ç€€æ„€æ¸€æ”€æ°€â€€ç€æ¤€ç€æ°€æ”€ã´€âœ€ä´€æ„€æ¤€æ¸€â€€ä¤€æ€æ”€æ„€âœ€ã¸€à´€à´€
<questionsAndAnswers>à¨ã°€æ €æ”€æ„€æ€æ¤€æ¸€æœ€ã¸€ã°€â„€å¬€äŒ€ä€ä„€å€ä„€å¬€å´€å´€ã¸€ã°€â¼€æ €æ”€æ„€æ€æ¤€æ¸€æœ€ã¸€à´€à´€
<question><![CDATA[<b>A Analyzing Primary Sources </b>What kind of teaching does the phrase "the use of the penâ€ refer to?]]></question>à¨ã°€æ„€æ¸€çŒ€çœ€æ”€çˆ€â¼€ã¸€à´€à´€
<ansCharCount>350</ansCharCount>à¨ã°€â¼€ç„€ç”€æ”€çŒ€ç€æ¤€æ¼€æ¸€çŒ€ä„€æ¸€æ€ä„€æ¸€çŒ€çœ
```

Looks scary..huh!!

Comment: What about `"\n\r"` ?

Comment: Maybe that sw.WriteLine is a problem.  Notice the Line in that command.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're reading the file line by line, so the line returned will *never* contain `\r`, `\n` or `\r\n` - as those are line separators.

The simplest approach is just to load the whole lot into memory, remove all the line breaks, then write it out:

```
string text = File.ReadAllText(sourceFileName);
text = text.Replace("\r", "").Replace("\n", "");
File.WriteAllText(sourceFileName, text);
```

Of course if you *only* want to remove carriage returns, just remove the `.Replace("\n", "")` in the above code.

EDIT: Now that we can see your file, there *is* no XML version 10, which suggests that the document is corrupt before you even get it. You should stop at this point and work backwards towards the source until you can get a valid XML file. There's no point in continuing with what you've currently got.

Comment: I see the content now but boxes(\r) are still displayed in the output

Comment: @user1837938: No, that output will have *no* carriage returns. There may be "boxes" for other reasons (e.g. the text isn't UTF-8) but they won't be carriage returns.

Comment: Ok..so what should i try for the boxes?

Comment: @user1837938: Well you should find out for sure what your encoding is, and potentially look at the file in a binary file viewer to see what those "box" characters really are in the binary data.

Comment: @user1837938: Yes, exactly.

Comment: @user1837938: No, you need to give the *hex* values (the bytes rather than how the hex editor chooses to interpret them) - and ideally let us know which encoding the file is in. Including the XML declaration would help, too.

Comment: <?xml version='10'?>, encoding declaration isn't specified in the file.

Comment: @user1837938: A version of *10*? Really? Not 1.0 perhaps? if the encoding isn't specified, it *should* be UTF-8 or UTF-16.

Comment: no..its 10 only...ok lets suppose it is UTF-8, then how should i proceed?

Comment: @user1837938: Well it sounds like it *isn't* UTF-8... or it's chronically broken. Please edit your question with the first (say) 32 bytes of the file in hex, as well as a hex section with the "odd" characters you're seeing.

Comment: Thanks Jon for your precious time..:)

Answer (score 0):

You can try another way like this :)

```
string foo = "First Line\nSecond Line\nThird Line";
foo = foo.Replace("\n", @"\" + "n");
```

The point is seperate \ and n(or r,t).